# Digg like site in Drupal

Tags: 7

Is there a way to create a "Digg" like site in Drupal. Basically I want to create a site based in "social voting". The users should be able to vote on specific items and based on this "democratic" behaviour the popularity of that particular item would be determined. I did come across a module "drigg" but was not too impressed with it. Any other alternatives ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check on the [voting api](http://drupal.org/project/votingapi) and maybe [fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar) if you need a rating system. As MPD suggested, Flag could be helpful too for this. But for a digg like site,... I think your safest bet might be [Vote Up/Down](http://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down). Then of course, you'd need to create views to display the front page, or each different category based on how many votes your users submit.

Comment: We make a Digg like site that we use to have our employees vote on the next features of our product. We use both the Vote UP/Down module and the voting api module.

Comment: Have you tried the D7 version of Vote Up/Down?  I have been turend off by the fact that it doesn't have a public dev version yet.

Answer (score 3):

An easy solution is to use the [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module to create your votes.  Then you can make a [View](http://drupal.org/project/views), sorted by flags and potentially with other criteria (like date windows).  You may also be able fold in criteria based on [Radioactivity](http://drupal.org/project/radioactivity).

Answer (score 0):

For historical reason I'd like to mention the [Drigg module](http://drupal.org/project/drigg) and the now defunct Drigg site aimed to build Digg in Drupal.